# facebook app authentication for background app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

i'm wondering if it's possible to build a facebook app that runs as a background process. basically, i'd collect data on the user's facebook usage and email them a monthly report. the question i have is that since facebook has an auth token with a maximum life of 60 days, is this feasible? i wouldn't want to have to have the user visit a website every other month just to keep using the app.

it seems to me that this is similar to the twitter facebook app. once you authenticate, if you never visit twitter.com again (instead, opting to only use twitter clients), how do they continue to post to your facebook account? doesn't their auth token expire after 60 days? is there something i'm missing?

Comment: if you're gonna downvote at least specify a reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to have some sort of user interaction to re-authenticate every once in a while.

What platform is your app being built on, facebook, mobile, webapp?

Comment: up in the air. the whole thing is up in the air pending some way of doing this. this is the feeling that i get from the docs but not sure how someone like twitter deals with this since most of their interactions on via 3rd party apps that interact with their api - they can't ensure users visit twitter.com to reauth against facebook! that's basically the same problem i have.

Comment: I haven't run into this issue myself, but I believe there is a workaround you can use to extend your access token's permissions. Then they only have to open your app once every 60 days to keep it alive.

See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107432/extending-access-token-expiration-not-functioning

and 

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/