# Facebook search one time login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to develop a site where the users login once with the facebook and in the future they only login to the site (not to facebook again). I am using the search request on behalf of the user so that the api limitations is relaxed.

After spending a good amount of time **I found the extended access solution**. ([Extending Access Token Expiration not functioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107432/extending-access-token-expiration-not-functioning)). But what I cannot understand is how, to populate the `$user` variable. I can set the access token via `setAccessToken()` function and using the saved value in database. But I cannot find a way to populate the $user variable. I am using 3.1.1 SDK. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in 3.1.1 with the certificate which may cause the `user` variable to be empty or 0. The most up to date version is v.3.2.2 and you should be using [`setExtendedAccessToken`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L351)

Comment: Thankyou. But will setting this set the $user also?

Comment: @Debian $user in the case of PHP SDK is just a user id, if you have a valid user it will return the corresponding id, if not 0. You set the $user such as in the example given in the PHP SDK `$user = $facebook->getUser();`

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this will solve the problem. I will try to update the sdk and work with that. If I have any problem, I will post here. Once again thank you

Comment: @Debian You grab the value from `getAccessToken()`

Comment: I am getting 0 for name. The access token is printed properly. I am using 3.2.2v sdk

Comment: @Debian what do you mean 0 for name, update your question with the code for reference

Comment: I found the error. The problem was when I updated the sdk, I forgot to turn off the ssl since I dont have certificate